# Find diff in properties set when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I was just wondering if there was a tool like this that existed, or something within Visual Studio 2010 that I just haven't come across before. I have a situation that arises that I'm sure many other people have ran into before. I debug into a method one time, and it works, another time, and it fails. I know (on the front end), what needs to happen for it to fail, and what needs to happen for it to pass, however I can't seem to find anything on the back-end that would show me the differences in all the properties that get passed through that method for each use case.

Is there a tool that can kind of analyze the objects in the code that I am passing through this method through each run, and then show me a diff of properties? Which ones are set/aren't set, which ones are different, etc.?

I normally wouldn't mind just blowing up the watches on each monitor and cruising through them, but we have a LOT of properties on these specific objects.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like [Mole 2010](http://www.molosoft.com/) work?  I know you can basically do a diff on objects to compare their properties, but I'm not sure if this would work in your situation with method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) will help you? It analyzes your code and created input values based on identified code paths and boundary cases.

Comment: That's definitely interesting and with some fooling around and a decent amount of use cases Pex might be a viable solution, but I want to give a little bit of time for anyway to see this that might have a solution that directly relates to what I needed to do. This is awesome though. I might use Pex for other things now.

Comment: It will not give a direct diff between properties, but it will automatically create unit tests with different input parameters to your method. Some will fail and some will not. You could then analyze those unit tests and find the difference between the input parameters.